# JQuery date time picker add 5 hours for current time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need two datetime pickers. In the first picker I need current date and time and in another picker I want to add 5 hours from current time. I tired with below code in jsfiddle. First picker working but second not working properly.

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d = new Date(); // for now
            datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes();
            $('#datepicker').val(datetext);
        },
    });
    });
    $(function() {
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d = new Date();

            // for now
            datetext=datetext+" "+d.setHours(d.getHours())+": "+d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes());`enter code here`
            $('#datepicker1').val(datetext);
        },
    });
    });
```

Comment: this is also not working                                                                          var d = new Date();
   
datetext=datetext+" "+d.setHours(d.getHours()+5)+": "+d.getMinutes();

Comment: Post the Jsfiddle link here

Comment: in first date picker am trying to disable date and time since it is already current date

Answer (score 2):

Added 5 hour to current time

```
    var d1 = new Date (),
    var d2 = new Date ( d1 );
    var addedhour=d2.setHours ( d1.getHours() + 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to add 5 hours from current time. Have a look at it :)

```
$(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
            onSelect: function(datetext){
                var d = new Date(); // for now
                datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes();
                $('#datepicker').val(datetext);
            },
        });
        });
        $(function() {
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
            onSelect: function(datetext){
                var d = new Date();
                d.setHours(d.getHours() + 5)

                // for now
                datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes();
                $('#datepicker1').val(datetext);
            },
        });
        });
```

Comment: hi it is not working for me can is their any changes i have to modify

Comment: Can you post your jsfiddle link ?

Comment: presently i am doing in http://jsfiddle.net/Qv36W/1/  this is am using for testing purpose only

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code,

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d = new Date(); // for now
            datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes();
            $('#datepicker').val(datetext);
        },
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
           var date2 = new Date(); 
           date2.setHours(date2.getHours()+5);
           $('#datepicker1').val(date2);
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi , it is not working date and time picker not popup

Answer (score 0):

```
this code is working 
$(function() {
$('#datetimepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    onSelect: function(datetext){
        var d = new Date(); // for now
        datetext=datetext+" "+d.getHours()+": "+d.getMinutes();
        $('#datetimepicker').val(datetext);
    },
});
});
$(function() {
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    onSelect: function(datetext){
        var d1 = new Date();
        var d2 = new Date( d1 );
        var addedhour=d2.setHours (d1.getHours()+5)
        // for now
        datetext=datetext+" "+d2.getHours()+": "+d2.getMinutes();
        $('#datetimepicker1').val(datetext);

    },
});
});
```

Comment: i want to add these features to my above code but it is not working $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        $("#datetimepicker").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);